# Receiving Request Data as an HTTP Server Properly Through Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, http, tcp

I'm trying to create a simple HTTP server for a learning experience. The server is supposed to receive the request data and send back response data. To get started, I created a `Socket`. I unfortunately don't know how to implement the receiving part properly.

I believe I cannot call `socket.Receive` and always expect all the data to transfer successfully. I would have to use a loop to continue streaming data. I don't understand which condition the program should stop streaming for data!

Checking if the amount of bytes read is 0 wouldn't work, as that only happens when the connection is closed. How should I implement it?

```
        var listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8070);
        listen.Start();
        var con = listen.AcceptSocket();
        listen.Stop();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (???) //what condition should stop the streaming?
            {
                var buffer = new byte[8000];
                int read = con.Receive(buffer);

                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out how to properly do it after a bit of failure and reasoning! In the HTTP specifications, it tells us that a request will be terminated after a , or "\r\n". So, here's the code that I ended up with to receive data properly:

```
        var listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8070);
        listen.Start();
        var con = listen.AcceptSocket();
        listen.Stop();

        string input = "";
        while (!input.EndsWith("\r\n\r\n"))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[8000];
            int read = con.Receive(buffer);
            input += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, read);
        }
```